# How can I speed up boot on one of my machines?

Tags: 10.10, boot, alsa, syslog

I have a Gateway all in one machine (2 gig Intel Core 2 Duo T7250 dual core processor, 2 gig RAM - [full specs](http://support.gateway.com/s/ONE/1014809R/1014809Rsp3.shtml)) on which I installed 10.10. Once it has booted it's fine, but it takes forever to boot.

This is what happens:
1. Boot starts with cursor flashing for about 10-15 seconds
2. Cursor disappears for 1.5 - 2 minutes
3. Cursor reappears, blinks a few seconds more, boot finishes in another 10 seconds
4. Login screen

I have another machine with marginal better specs that boots up in no time (basically the above minus the two minute delay).

Things I've done:

- enabled verbose mode for grub >> nothing is showing until **after** 2 minute pause.
- checked syslog >> last message before pause is a message from alsa saying the process is already running (or something similar... going from memory here...)

It could be something sound related as the built in speakers are not working (sound card is recognized though and headphones work).

Anyway, it's not the end of the world, but it's annoying and I'd like to know what's going on... Many thanks, and let me know if more info is needed.

**Edit**

No matter what I tried I could not get into safe mode... Shift didn't work and Esc didn't work. I did boot into recovery mode using startupmanager which didn't make a difference.

I installed Bootchart per Maxime, and according to bootchart it takes about 20s to boot up, which is pretty much the time from the moment the cursor reappears to the time the login screen shows up...

Comment: How much time does it take to boot to safe mode?

Comment: @Javier Good question... I haven't tried that. Will try that tonight and update question.

Answer (score 4):

You should check your last bootchart in `/var/log/bootchart`.

I don't remender if bootchart is part of the standard installation but if not, only `sudo apt-get install bootchart pybootchartgui` and reboot. Also see [here](http://www.bootchart.org/index.html) for more information.

There you should be able to analyze what takes so much time ! On my 5 years old laptop, it "only" takes 65s to boot up. What duration is reported on your's ? This tool helped me to resolve some issues : fsck was always checking all partitions and ntp-date wanted to synchronize the clock while the network connection wasn't already enabled.

I would also recommend to check the system logs for errors or warnings and to correlate them with the bootchart but as you already did it, it won't be of much help.

As you were able to see the cursor before the 2min pause I suppose the issue isn't grub related.

Also remove quiet and splash boot options in grub and, as Javier suggested, try to boot in safe mode.

Good luck !

Comment: Oh wow - that looks like an awesome tool! Many thanks - will give that a go.

Comment: Heh... So according to bootchart it only takes 20s to boot. My guess is it is triggered after the delay. Still, it's a very cool tool; thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it did not help you to solve your problem...